# RecyclerView pull UP to refresh

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

How can I detect when the recycler view is at the bottom of the list, and not the bottom of just the screen, but the last item in the RecyclerView. Right now im using the SwipeRefreshLayout but I cant set it to be Pull Up.

Comment: Are you using your own LayoutManager?

Comment: check my git project https://github.com/jaisoni/RecyclerViewAndroid

Answer (score 4):

Use this code inside `onScrolled()` callback.

```
int lastVisibleItem = ((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();

if (lastVisibleItem >= totalItemCount - 10) {
   loadMore();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

add a scroll listener.

`RecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener listener)`